# Как предотвратить блокирование страницы с которой осуществляется редирект в андроид?

Tags: javascript, android

Есть задача, при нажатии на ссылку "Скачать приложение" - происходит переход на страницу с инструкцией, и затем сразу идет переход в PlayMarket.

на странице с инструкцией стоит скрипт который после загрузки  выполняет:

```
location.href = platformDownloadLink
```

На андроиде столкнулся с тем, что при перенаправлении через js пользователя на другую страницу (в нашем случае плоеймаркет), страница с инструкцией закрывается и происходит возврат к главной странице сайта, и выскакивает системное сообщение (**Backward redirection blocked** Internet automatically stops websites from taking you to ads or unintended pages when you tap back button. You can turn this off in settings)

Понимаю что проблема из-за авто-редиректа на плеймаркет, но как это тогда правильно сделать, чтобы и страница с инструкцией открывалась и сразу начиналось скачивание (переход в стор)

Comment: Не понятно какой смысл в инструкции если сразу переход в стор. Кто ее прочитать успеет за секунду или две? Может прочел и нажал будет вернее? Либо сразу в стор.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja такая задача, нужно чтобы после перехода в стор и вернувшись в браузер была страница инструкции, если делать ручной переход по кнопке - все ок, нужно автоматически

Comment: Это даже скорее страница спасибо за скачивание, так будет правильнее, на десктопных платформах инструкции на мобильных страница спасибо, суть проблемы от этого не меняется, на андроид после авто редиректа в стор страница схлопывается и открывается главная